# Split date range into several chunks ending by YYYY-12-31

Tags: r, date, date-range

```
df <- data.frame(group = c("a", "a", "b", "b"),
                 start = c("2017-05-01", "2019-04-03", "2011-03-03", "2014-05-07"),
                 end = c("2018-09-01", "2020-04-03", "2012-05-03", "2016-04-02"))
```

Let's say I have the following df:

```
  group      start        end
1     a 2017-05-01 2018-09-01
2     a 2019-04-03 2020-04-03
3     b 2011-03-03 2012-05-03
4     b 2014-05-07 2016-04-02
```

I want to get it into this format, with each record split into starting date and 31/12 of that and subsequent years:

```
  group      start        end
1     a 2017-05-01 2017-12-31
2     a 2018-01-01 2018-09-01
3     a 2019-04-03 2019-12-31
4     a 2020-01-01 2020-04-03
5     b 2011-03-03 2011-12-31
6     b 2012-01-01 2012-05-03
7     b 2014-05-07 2014-12-31
8     b 2015-01-01 2015-12-31
9     b 2016-01-01 2016-04-02
```

Any ideas on how to tackle this?

**Edit:**

My primary concerns are not the date ranges that are within the same year. However, as chinsoon12 pointed out, it would indeed be helpful if the approach could handle them as well, as for instance in this dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(group = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c"),
                 start = c("2017-05-01", "2019-04-03", "2011-03-03", "2014-05-07", "2017-02-01"),
                 end = c("2018-09-01", "2020-04-03", "2012-05-03", "2016-04-02", "2017-04-05"))
```

The end result would leave the last line as it was:

```
   group      start        end
1      a 2017-05-01 2017-12-31
2      a 2018-01-01 2018-09-01
3      a 2019-04-03 2019-12-31
4      a 2020-01-01 2020-04-03
5      b 2011-03-03 2011-12-31
6      b 2012-01-01 2012-05-03
7      b 2014-05-07 2014-12-31
8      b 2015-01-01 2015-12-31
9      b 2016-01-01 2016-04-02
10     c 2017-02-01 2017-04-05
```

Comment: what if the start and end are within the same year? is that possible in your dataset?

Comment: Valid point, but not a must - see the updated question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A possible solution with [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[df[, rep(.I, 1 + year(end) - year(start))]
   ][, `:=` (start = pmax(start[1], as.Date(paste0(year(start[1]) + 0:(.N-1), '-01-01'))),
             end = pmin(end[.N], as.Date(paste0(year(end[.N]) - (.N-1):0, '-12-31'))))
     , by = .(group, rleid(start))][]
```

which gives:

> ```
>     group      start        end
>  1:     a 2017-05-01 2017-12-31
>  2:     a 2018-01-01 2018-09-01
>  3:     a 2019-04-03 2019-12-31
>  4:     a 2020-01-01 2020-04-03
>  5:     b 2011-03-03 2011-12-31
>  6:     b 2012-01-01 2012-05-03
>  7:     b 2014-05-07 2014-12-31
>  8:     b 2015-01-01 2015-12-31
>  9:     b 2016-01-01 2016-04-02
> 10:     c 2017-02-01 2017-04-05
> ```

Two alternative solutions with [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table):

```
# alternative 1:
df[, ri := rowid(group)
   ][df[, rep(.I, 1 + year(end) - year(start))]
     ][, `:=` (start = if (.N == 1) start else c(start[1], as.Date(paste0(year(start[1]) + 1:(.N-1), '-01-01') )),
               end = if (.N == 1) end else c(as.Date(paste0(year(end[.N]) - (.N-1):1, '-12-31') ), end[.N]))
       , by = .(group, ri)][, ri := NULL][]

# alternative 2:
df[, ri := rowid(group)
   ][df[, rep(.I, 1 + year(end) - year(start))]
     ][, `:=` (start = pmax(start[1], as.Date(paste0(year(start[1]) + 0:(.N-1), '-01-01'))),
               end = pmin(end[.N], as.Date(paste0(year(end[.N]) - (.N-1):0, '-12-31'))))
       , by = .(group, ri)][, ri := NULL][]
```

---

Used data:

```
df <- data.frame(group = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c"),
                 start = c("2017-05-01", "2019-04-03", "2011-03-03", "2014-05-07", "2017-02-01"),
                 end = c("2018-09-01", "2020-04-03", "2012-05-03", "2016-04-02", "2017-04-05")) 
df[2:3] <- lapply(df[2:3], as.Date)
```

Comment: Thank you, very neat indeed! Please see the updated question - it would be good if the approach handles the within the same year ranges as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very efficient. I only run into issues if start & end date are the same, but these I need to filter out anyway.

Answer (score 3):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
df%>%
  mutate(end=as.Date(end),
     start=as.Date(start),
     diff=Map(":",0,1+year(end)-year(start)-1))%>%
  unnest()%>%
  mutate(end=pmin(end,as.Date(paste0(year(start)+diff,"-12-31"))),
         start=pmax(start,as.Date(paste0(year(start)+diff,"-1-1"))),
         diff=NULL)

A tibble: 9 x 3
  group start      end       
  <fct> <date>     <date>    
1 a     2017-05-02 2017-12-31
2 a     2018-01-01 2018-09-01
3 a     2019-04-03 2019-12-31
4 a     2020-01-01 2020-04-03
5 b     2020-01-01 2011-12-31
6 b     2012-01-01 2012-05-03
7 b     2014-05-07 2014-12-31
8 b     2015-01-01 2015-12-31
9 b     2015-01-01 2016-04-02
```

with the updated data just ran this exact function you will get:

```
 group      start        end
1      a 2017-05-01 2017-12-31
2      a 2018-01-01 2018-09-01
3      a 2019-04-03 2019-12-31
4      a 2020-01-01 2020-04-03
5      b 2011-03-03 2011-12-31
6      b 2012-01-01 2012-05-03
7      b 2014-05-07 2014-12-31
8      b 2015-01-01 2015-12-31
9      b 2016-01-01 2016-04-02
10     c 2017-02-01 2017-04-05
```

Comment: Thank you! This handles the additional requirement as well. However, as this is an additional requirement not in the initial question, I will wait a day to see other possible updates/responses & then close the topic.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer can be very useful if piping with dplyr, but given that I need this as part of a script where only data.table is used because of efficiency & dependencies would be unnecessary, I checked Jaap's answer as most useful (although the internal logic is similar).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a no-tidyverse/no-data.table version:

```
df <- data.frame(group = c("a", "a", "b", "b"),
                 start = c("2017-05-01", "2019-04-03", "2011-03-03", "2014-05-07"),
                 end = c("2018-09-01", "2020-04-03", "2012-05-03", "2016-04-02"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
# added stringsAsFactors =FALSE to your df for sanity
# reformatting start and end as Date  
df$start <- as.Date(df$start)
df$end <- as.Date(df$end)

dfs <- split(df, rownames(df))
# split the data frame by rows

res <- do.call(rbind, lapply(dfs, function(.){
  s <- seq(from=.$start, to=.$end, by="day")
  # sequence form df$start to df$end, by days
  y <- format(s, "%Y")
  # years of that sequence
  s2 <- as.character(s)
  # formatting s as character -- otherwise sapply will get rid of the 
  # Date class and the result will look as numeric
  ys <- split(s2,y)
  # split the sequence by years
  data.frame(group=.$group, start=sapply(ys, head,1), end = sapply(ys, tail, 1), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  # take the first and last element from each "sub-vector" of the split sequence
}))
rownames(res) <- NULL # kill the nasty rownames
res

  group      start        end
1     a 2017-05-01 2017-12-31
2     a 2018-01-01 2018-09-01
3     a 2019-04-03 2019-12-31
4     a 2020-01-01 2020-04-03
5     b 2011-03-03 2011-12-31
6     b 2012-01-01 2012-05-03
7     b 2014-05-07 2014-12-31
8     b 2015-01-01 2015-12-31
9     b 2016-01-01 2016-04-02
```

Notice that the result has `start` and `end` columns as `character` as it was in your original data frame.

I'm sorry for the way base R treats Date (and POSIXct) objects - you never know when they may lose their class and become simple numbers. Here I avoided this "feature" by treating dates as character, except when date operations were needed e.g in creating the sequence of days.

Comment: Thank you! I like the approach - simple and effective, no dependencies. Handles the additional requirement as well - leaving the date ranges within the same year as they are. However, as this is an additional requirement not in the initial question, I will wait a day to see other possible updates/responses & then close the topic.