# Categorize time intervals to dates in R

Tags: r, timestamp, data.table, intervals, tidyverse

I have a very large dataset where I need to split time intervals into dates for further analysis.

Below an example of my dataset:

```
require(data.table)

RawDT = data.table(
   TimeStampID = c("4"),
  DateTimeFrom = c("2019-02-10 16:28:03"),
    DateTimeTo = c("2019-02-12 02:04:03")
)
```

Below is the desired result:

```
ResultDT = data.table(
           ID = c("1","2","3"),
  TimeStampID = c("4","4","4"),
           DS = c("2019-02-10","2019-02-11","2019-02-12"),
     TimeFrom = c("16:28:03","00:00:00","00:00:00"),
       TimeTo = c("23:59:59","23:59:59","02:04:03")
)
```

Can anyone guide me to which function to use to achieve ResultDT from RawDT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this is borderline duplicate - so I encourage the moderators to close the topic if they consider it appropriate to do so, and I'll delete my post.

However, I had a similar (but not exactly identical, that's why I'm answering) problem with beginning and end of year ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50729220/split-date-into-several-chunks-ending-by-yyyy-12-31)), and @Jaap created a great (and succinct!) solution the logic of which can be applied also here, for instance:

```
library(data.table)

RawDT[, `:=` (DateTimeFrom = as.POSIXct(DateTimeFrom), DateTimeTo = as.POSIXct(DateTimeTo))]

RawDT[RawDT[, rep(.I, 1 + as.Date(DateTimeTo) - as.Date(DateTimeFrom))]
   ][, `:=` (DateTimeFrom = pmax(DateTimeFrom[1], as.POSIXct(paste0(as.Date(DateTimeFrom[1]) + 0:(.N-1), ' 00:00:00'))),
             DateTimeTo = pmin(DateTimeTo[.N], as.POSIXct(paste0(as.Date(DateTimeTo[.N]) - (.N-1):0, ' 23:59:59'))))
     , by = .(TimeStampID, rleid(DateTimeFrom))][]
```

I've added an additional group to your `DT` just to test the functionality:

```
RawDT = data.table(
  TimeStampID = c("4", "5"),
  DateTimeFrom = c("2019-02-10 16:28:03", "2019-03-15 12:28:03"),
  DateTimeTo = c("2019-02-12 02:04:03", "2019-03-20 14:45:00")
)
```

And the output for the above code would be:

```
   TimeStampID        DateTimeFrom          DateTimeTo
1:           4 2019-02-10 16:28:03 2019-02-10 23:59:59
2:           4 2019-02-11 00:00:00 2019-02-11 23:59:59
3:           4 2019-02-12 00:00:00 2019-02-12 02:04:03
4:           5 2019-03-15 12:28:03 2019-03-15 23:59:59
5:           5 2019-03-16 00:00:00 2019-03-16 23:59:59
6:           5 2019-03-17 00:00:00 2019-03-17 23:59:59
7:           5 2019-03-18 00:00:00 2019-03-18 23:59:59
8:           5 2019-03-19 00:00:00 2019-03-19 23:59:59
9:           5 2019-03-20 00:00:00 2019-03-20 14:45:00
```

Comment: You're welcome, but don't thank me - have a look at the topic I've mentioned and learn from the posts there, there were solutions with other approaches as well, and they can be potentially applied to any similar problem that has to do with ranges and cuts (years, days, etc.).