# Split a rows into two when a date range spans a change in calendar year

Tags: r

I am trying to figure out how to add a row when a date range spans a calendar year. Below is a minimal reprex:

I have a date frame like this:

```r
have <- data.frame(
  from = c(as.Date('2018-12-15'), as.Date('2019-12-20'), as.Date('2019-05-13')), 
  to = c(as.Date('2019-06-20'), as.Date('2020-01-25'), as.Date('2019-09-10'))
)
have
#>         from         to
#> 1 2018-12-15 2019-06-20
#> 2 2019-12-20 2020-01-25
#> 3 2019-05-13 2019-09-10
```

I want a data.frame that splits into two rows when `to` and `from` span a calendar year.

```
want <- data.frame(
  from = c(as.Date('2018-12-15'), as.Date('2019-01-01'), as.Date('2019-12-20'), as.Date('2020-01-01'), as.Date('2019-05-13')), 
  to = c(as.Date('2018-12-31'), as.Date('2019-06-20'), as.Date('2019-12-31'), as.Date('2020-01-25'), as.Date('2019-09-10'))
)
want
#>         from         to
#> 1 2018-12-15 2018-12-31
#> 2 2019-01-01 2019-06-20
#> 3 2019-12-20 2019-12-31
#> 4 2020-01-01 2020-01-25
#> 5 2019-05-13 2019-09-10
```

I am wanting to do this because for a particular row, I want to know how many days are in each year.

```
want$time_diff_by_year <- difftime(want$to, want$from)
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Any base R, tidyverse solutions would be much appreciated.

Comment: yes in the real one

Comment: i've added two more rows. Does that work?

Comment: Might it ever be that a row spans *two* years, e.g. `2018-05-13` to `2020-03-10`? And if so, would you want the obvious thing, i.e. have that broken out into three rows?

Comment: Related: [Split date into several chunks ending by YYYY-12-31](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50729220/split-date-into-several-chunks-ending-by-yyyy-12-31)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can determine the additional years needed for your date intervals with `map2`, then `unnest` to create additional rows for each year.

Then, you can identify date intervals of intersections between partial years and a full calendar year. This will keep the partial years starting Jan 1 or ending Dec 31 for a given year.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

have %>%
  mutate(date_int = interval(from, to),
         year = map2(year(from), year(to), seq)) %>%
  unnest(year) %>%
  mutate(year_int = interval(as.Date(paste0(year, '-01-01')), as.Date(paste0(year, '-12-31'))),
         year_sect = intersect(date_int, year_int),
         from_new = as.Date(int_start(year_sect)),
         to_new = as.Date(int_end(year_sect))) %>%
  select(from_new, to_new)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  from_new   to_new    
  <date>     <date>    
1 2018-12-15 2018-12-31
2 2019-01-01 2019-06-20
3 2019-12-20 2019-12-31
4 2020-01-01 2020-01-25
5 2019-05-13 2019-09-10
```