# Disaggregate data over different years with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame and I need to dis-aggregate it over different years. The data frame is:

```
df = data.frame(x = 1000, time_L = '2018-12-30', time_R = "2020-10-30")
```

and I need the output to be like this:

```
  time_L     time_R    diff xprime
 2018-12-30 2018-12-31  2      3
 2019-01-01 2019-12-31 365    544
 2020-01-01 2020-10-30 304    453
```

xprime is dis-aggregated over each time interval based on the number of days  in it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What a nice first question! Clear, reproducible, and interesting!

Comment: Related: [Split a rows into two when a date range spans a change in calendar year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61828819/split-a-rows-into-two-when-a-date-range-spans-a-change-in-calendar-year) as well as [Split date range into several chunks ending by YYYY-12-31](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50729220/split-date-range-into-several-chunks-ending-by-yyyy-12-31)

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(across(contains('time'),ymd),
         start = list(seq(floor_date(time_L, "year"), time_R, "1 year")),
         end = list(lead(start[[1]] - 1, default = last(time_R)))) %>%
  unnest(c(start, end)) %>%
  mutate(start = pmax(start, time_L),
         diff = as.numeric(end-start) + 1,
         xprime = round(prop.table(diff)*x))
  
# A tibble: 3 x 7
      x time_L     time_R     start      end         diff xprime
  <dbl> <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <dbl>  <dbl>
1  1000 2018-12-30 2020-10-30 2018-12-30 2018-12-31     2      3
2  1000 2018-12-30 2020-10-30 2019-01-01 2019-12-31   365    544
3  1000 2018-12-30 2020-10-30 2020-01-01 2020-10-30   304    453
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. There is a small issue here with using round. when I tried your code for a different time interval, the sum of xprime is not equal to x.  df = data.frame(x = 1000, time_L = '2010-01-01', time_R = '2020-01-25')

Comment: @NedaJalali that is because of the rounding error. It has nothing to do with the code. For example, just allow the xprime to be fractions and it will sum to 1000